# How to highlight text regardless whether uppercase or lowercase as long as they match in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React from "react";

const Highlighter = ({
  children,
  highlight,
}: {
  children: any;
  highlight: any;
}) => {
  if (!highlight) return children;
  const regexp = new RegExp(highlight, "g");
  const matches = children.toString().match(regexp);
  var parts = children
    .toString()
    .split(new RegExp(`${highlight.replace()}`, "g"));

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (i !== parts.length - 1) {
      let match = matches[i];
      // While the next part is an empty string, merge the corresponding match with the current
      // match into a single <span/> to avoid consequent spans with nothing between them.
      while (parts[i + 1] === "") {
        match += matches[++i];
      }

      parts[i] = (
        <React.Fragment key={i}>
          {parts[i]}
          <span className="highlighted">{match}</span>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  }
  return <div className="highlighter">{parts}</div>;
};

export default Highlighter;
```

The code above are able to highlight the text as used below:

```js
<Highlighter highlight="text">
    This is some random text
</Highlighter>
```

and this will result in the `text` being highlighted. However, if I change the highlight attribute to: `highlight="Text"`, it wouldn't highlight the `text` anymore because there is an uppercase T. How do I modify this code so that it would even match lower/uppercase letter?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags

Answer (score 0):

You will need to transform the text and the hightlight to lower case , after matching the word use the index of the matched element ( start index and end index ) to add css class based on if the letter is between these indexes .

I made an  [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bohr-r9x3w6?file=/src/App.js) that might help you out using your code .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @epascarello comment, I have updated the function as below:

```js
const Highlighter = ({
  children,
  highlight,
}: {
  children: any;
  highlight: any;
}) => {
  if (!highlight) return children;
  const regexp = new RegExp(highlight, "i"); // HERE IS THE CHANGE
  const matches = children.toString().match(regexp);
  var parts = children
    .toString()
    .split(new RegExp(`${highlight.replace()}`, "i")); // HERE IS THE CHANGE

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (i !== parts.length - 1) {
      let match = matches[i];
      // While the next part is an empty string, merge the corresponding match with the current
      // match into a single <span/> to avoid consequent spans with nothing between them.
      while (parts[i + 1] === "") {
        match += matches[++i];
      }

      parts[i] = (
        <React.Fragment key={i}>
          {parts[i]}
          <span className="highlighted">{match}</span>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  }
  return <div className="highlighter">{parts}</div>;
};
```

So, instead of using the flag `g` which is for global search, I changed it to flag `i` which is used for insensitive case search. This achieves the result that I wanted which is to highlight the text regardless of uppercase/lowercase.